# Python unit tests for storing and loading objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, serialization

I wrote some code and thought I may get better with some feedback. I program for almost 5 years, mainly in python.

I care most about the unit testing.
I am not really sure, how industry standard unit tests in python look like.

*storable.py*

```py
import os
import uuid
import logging
from os.path import *

from typing import Type, List, Optional, Iterable, Union
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)


# TODO: remove
class DirectorySave(ABC):
    def __init__(self, uuid_: bytes = None):
        if uuid_ is None:
            uuid_ = uuid.uuid4()
        else:
            uuid_ = uuid.UUID(bytes=uuid_)
        self.uuid = uuid_

    @abstractmethod
    def save(self, path: str, force: bool = False):
        """
        This method saves this object to a directory.
        :param path: this should be a string, and a valid and existing path
        :param force: if this is enabled, any error will not crash the saving process,
                      whether skip the failing object
        :return: the save path
        """

    @classmethod
    @abstractmethod
    def load(cls, path: str, force: bool = False):
        """
        This method loads a new object from a directory
        :param path: this should be a string, and a valid and existing path
        :param force: if this is enabled, any error will not crash the saving process,
                      whether skip the failing object
        :return: the loaded object
        """

    @property
    def save_name(self):
        return self.uuid.hex


class Storable(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def save(self, path: str, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        This method should be overwritten to provide save implementation.
        :param path: this will be created, if it doesn't exist.
        """

    @classmethod
    @abstractmethod
    def load(cls, path: str, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        This method should be overwritten to provide load implementation.
        :param path: this should be an existing path.
        """


# TODO: remove
class SequentialSave(DirectorySave, ABC):
    """ This class saves a sequence of DirectorySave instances, to a directory. """

    @staticmethod
    def _validate_path(path):
        path = abspath(path)
        assert isdir(path), ('the given path does not exist', path)
        return path


    @classmethod
    def save_seq(cls, path: str, objects: List[DirectorySave], loader: Type[DirectorySave], force: bool = False) -> List[DirectorySave]:
        """
        This method saves all given objects to a save path.

        NOTE: This method should be called from self.save().
        :param path: this should be a string, and a valid and existing path
        :param loader: this should be the class used for loading (here only for assertions)
        :param objects: this should be a list of :type self.loader: instances
        :param force: if this is enabled, any error will not crash the saving process,
                      whether skip the failing object
        :return: a list with the saved objects
        """
        msg = 'could not save object %s (%s)'
        path = cls._validate_path(path)
        saved_objects = list()

        for obj in objects:
            assert isinstance(obj, loader), 'invalid object type'
            save_path = join(path, obj.save_name)

            if not isdir(save_path):
                try:
                    os.mkdir(save_path)
                except Exception as e:
                    log.error(msg, str(obj), 'mkdir failed', exc_info=e)
                    if force:
                        continue
                    raise

            try:
                obj.save(save_path, force=force)
            except Exception as e:
                log.error(msg, str(obj), 'save method failed', exc_info=e)
                if force:
                    continue
                raise

            saved_objects.append(obj)

        return saved_objects

    @classmethod
    def load_seq(cls, path: str, loader: Type[DirectorySave], force: bool = False) -> List[DirectorySave]:
        """
        Load a sequence of objects from a directory.
        NOTE: This method should only be called from self.load()
        :param path: this should be a string, and a valid and existing path
        :param loader: this should be the class used for loading
        :param force: if this is enabled, any error will not crash the saving process,
                      whether skip the failing object
        :return: all loaded objects
        """
        msg = 'could not load object %s (%s)'
        path = cls._validate_path(path)
        loaded_objects = list()

        for subdirectory in os.listdir(path):
            try:
                data = bytes.fromhex(subdirectory)
            except ValueError as e:
                log.error('could not load subdirectory, %s is not hexadecimal', subdirectory, exc_info=e)
                if force:
                    continue
                raise

            try:
                obj = loader.load(join(path, subdirectory), force=force)
                obj.uuid = uuid.UUID(bytes=data)
                loaded_objects.append(obj)
            except Exception as e:
                log.error(msg, subdirectory, 'load method failed', exc_info=e)
                if force:
                    continue
                raise

        return loaded_objects


class StorableTypedDict(dict, Storable):
    """
    This class can save its content to disk.
    It is a subclass from dict, and handles it keys as subdirectories in the save path.
    The values are saved by a user defined implementation.
    """

    def __init__(self, t: Type[Storable], *args, **kwargs):
        """
        :param t: The type of the stored values. This should be user defined.
        """
        super(StorableTypedDict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._type = t

        assert all(map(lambda i: isinstance(i, t), self.values()))

    def save(self, path: str, skip: bool = False, *args, **kwargs) -> dict:
        """
        Save the entire content of this dictionary to disk.
        :param path: a directory to save to.
        :param skip: if this is True, failing save calls are not fatal.
        :return: a list with all failed save calls.
        """
        os.makedirs(path, exist_ok=True)
        failed = dict()

        for key, value in self.items():
            assert isinstance(key, str), 'names should be string'
            assert isinstance(value, self._type), f'{value} is not of type {self._type}'
            item_path = join(path, key)
            os.makedirs(item_path, exist_ok=True)

            try:
                value.save(item_path)
            except Exception as e:
                log.error('could not save item %s %s', key, value, exc_info=e)
                if skip:
                    failed[key] = e
                    continue
                raise

        return failed

    @classmethod
    def load(cls, path: str, load_as: Type[Storable] = Storable,
             skip: bool = False, *args, **kwargs) -> Union['StorableTypedDict', tuple]:
        """
        Load all subdirectories into a dictionary with a given loader.
        :param path: a directory to load from.
        :param load_as: the loader class. It will be used to load, each individual subdir.
        :param skip: if this is True, failing load calls are not fatal.
        :return: if skip is True this return a tuple, with
                 1. the loaded dictionary
                 2. the failed load calls, stored inside a dictionary
                 else it only returns the loaded dictionary.
        """
        assert isdir(path)
        loaded = cls(load_as)
        failed = dict()

        for directory in os.listdir(path):
            dir_path = join(path, directory)
            if not isdir(dir_path):
                continue

            try:
                loaded[directory] = load_as.load(dir_path)
            except Exception as e:
                log.error('could not load item from %s', dir_path)
                if skip:
                    failed[directory] = e
                raise

        if skip:
            return loaded, failed
        return loaded
```

*test_storable.py*

```py
import os
import unittest
from os.path import *
from functools import partial

from application.storage.storable import Storable, StorableTypedDict
from ...test_utils import *


class DataMixin:
    FILE_NAME = 'test.txt'
    MESSAGE = 'this is a test'


class CustomStorable(Storable, DataMixin):
    def save(self, path: str, *args, **kwargs):
        os.makedirs(path, exist_ok=True)
        with open(join(path, self.FILE_NAME), 'wt') as f:
            f.write(self.MESSAGE)

    @classmethod
    def load(cls, path: str, *args, **kwargs):
        assert isdir(path), 'given path does not exist'
        with open(join(path, cls.FILE_NAME), 'rt') as f:
            assert f.read() == cls.MESSAGE

        return cls()

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, self.__class__)


class FailingCustomStorable(CustomStorable):
    class CustomException(Exception): ...

    def save(self, path: str, *args, **kwargs):
        raise self.CustomException

    @classmethod
    def load(cls, path: str, *args, **kwargs):
        raise cls.CustomException


class TestStorableTypedDict(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_init(self):
        storable_dict = StorableTypedDict(
            CustomStorable,
            {'name1': CustomStorable(), 'name2': CustomStorable()}
        )

        assert 'name1' in storable_dict
        assert 'name2' in storable_dict

    def test_save(self):
        # success
        @tmp_dir
        def _(path):
            storable_dict = StorableTypedDict(
                CustomStorable,
                {'name1': CustomStorable(), 'name2': CustomStorable()}
            )

            failed = storable_dict.save(path, skip=False)
            assert not failed

            files = os.listdir(path)
            for key in storable_dict.keys():
                assert key in files, '%s is was not created' % key
                assert isdir(join(path, key)), '%s is no dir' % key

        # fail
        @tmp_dir
        def _(path):
            storable_dict = StorableTypedDict(
                CustomStorable,
                {'name1': CustomStorable(), 'name2': FailingCustomStorable()}
            )

            self.assertRaises(
                FailingCustomStorable.CustomException,
                lambda: storable_dict.save(path, skip=False)
            )

        # suppressed fail
        @tmp_dir
        def _(path):
            storable_dict = StorableTypedDict(
                CustomStorable,
                {'name1': CustomStorable(), 'name2': FailingCustomStorable()}
            )

            try:
                failed = storable_dict.save(path, skip=True)
                assert len(failed) == 1, failed
                assert 'name2' in failed, failed
                assert isinstance(failed['name2'], FailingCustomStorable.CustomException)

            except FailingCustomStorable.CustomException:
                self.fail('the save exception was not handled')

    def test_load(self):
        # success
        @tmp_dir
        def _(path):
            storable_dict = StorableTypedDict(
                CustomStorable,
                {'name1': CustomStorable(), 'name2': CustomStorable()}
            )

            failed = storable_dict.save(path, skip=False)
            assert not failed

            loaded = StorableTypedDict.load(path, load_as=CustomStorable, skip=False)
            assert not isinstance(loaded, tuple)
            assert storable_dict == loaded, (storable_dict, loaded)

        # failure
        @tmp_dir
        def _(path):
            storable_dict = StorableTypedDict(
                CustomStorable,
                {'name1': CustomStorable(), 'name2': CustomStorable()}
            )

            failed = storable_dict.save(path, skip=False)
            assert not failed

            self.assertRaises(
                FailingCustomStorable.CustomException,
                lambda: StorableTypedDict.load(path, load_as=FailingCustomStorable, skip=False)
            )

        # suppressed failure
        @tmp_dir
        def _(path):
            storable_dict = StorableTypedDict(
                CustomStorable,
                {'name1': CustomStorable(), 'name2': CustomStorable()}
            )

            failed = storable_dict.save(path, skip=False)
            assert not failed

            try:
                loaded, failed = StorableTypedDict.load(path, load_as=FailingCustomStorable, skip=True)

                storable_dict.pop('name2')
                assert loaded == storable_dict
                assert 'name2' in failed
                assert isinstance(failed['name2'], FailingCustomStorable.CustomException)

            except FailingCustomStorable.CustomException:
                self.fail('the load exception was not handled')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

*test_utils.py*

```py
import shutil
import tempfile

DELETE_TMP_DIRS = True

def tmp_dir(fn):
    path = tempfile.mkdtemp()
    try:
        return fn(path)
    finally:
        if DELETE_TMP_DIRS:
            shutil.rmtree(path)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You have 3 `def _(path)` - it seems really ugly and gives no hint about the purpose of those methods. Also I'm not sure why they are inner methods inside test methods that you never seem to call.
2. few unused imports
3. As I mentioned on SO, when using `unittest` you should use `unittest.TestCase.assert...()` methods, not standard Python assert statement.
4. You have a lot of repeated code in those weird `_` methods, yet you don't make any use of `setUp` and `tearDown` methods available for `unittest.TestCase`.